# PHP not showing up values for Post function

Tags: php, html

Hye there I'm new to PHP and learning to my own I have a simple HTML form as:

```
<form action="file:///C|/wamp/www/welcome.php" method="POST"> 
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
Enter your age: <input type="text" name="age" /> 
<input type="submit" />
```

and my PHP file is:

```
<body>
HELLO
<?php 
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old!
?>
</body>
```

the problem is that when i click on my submit button it only shows the following output:

```
HELLO Welcome .
You are years old!
```

I mean the output is not showing up the contents from the POST Function! so is it me doing something wrong or so. I am new to PHP and want to learn it can somebody help me please
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path for your form action must be a valid web path. Not a file path on your computer:

```
<form action="/welcome.php" method="POST">
```

or

```
<form action="http://localhost/welcome.php" method="POST">
```

You also mix HTML in your PHP which should be throwing you a syntax error. When you fix the above that will error out on you.

```
<body>
HELLO
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old!
</body>
```

Comment: +1 Yepper. I posted a comment above but I deleted it. The first and last tags needed to be omitted. You've got this one under control ;-)

Comment: You're always one step ahead of me. But I blame the cat on my lap for this episode! :)

Comment: Well, yes and no. Remember, I type faster ;-) that doesn't necessarily mean I always get it right! haha --- I had cats, now they've been replaced by "cacti". They're meaner.

Comment: Thanks and regards you helped me I am totally new and learning PHP thanks so nice of you